# Liferay 6.2: How to get window state in JSP?

Tags: liferay, liferay-6, liferay-theme, liferay-aui, liferay-ide

I have to get current Liferay Window state in jsp file. 
I have tried

```
WindowState.class.toString()
```

It is giving result `class javax.portlet.WindowState`

I also try for `actionResponse.getWindowState().toString()`
It is giving the same result as above.

I just want to check in my jsp file portlet is in which state, and write the conditions accordingly. I am looking for the condition like    `(actionResponse.getWindowState().toString()).equals(WindowState.MAXIMIZED)`

I am getting exception in above condition. By which means I can get current state of the portlet in JSP.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you want is one of the following:

```
portletRequest.getWindowState() == WindowState.MAXIMIZED
actionRequest.getWindowState() == WindowState.MAXIMIZED
renderRequest.getWindowState() == WindowState.MAXIMIZED
```

(You can use `.equals()` on the state as well, but that is not necessary, as it is a constant value).

The `toString()` method of any `Class` object will always return `class` + the class name. I don't see why you are even try to do that - it seems that you need to investigate the differences between of objects, classes, variables and constants.